# SELECT "as" nomenclature for a column

Tags: php, mysql, select, recordset

Seems simple but what am I doing wrong here? I just want the max value in a column for a given vendor ID. Can I use the `as` clause in a recordset?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT max(container_no) as newcontainer 
  FROM FETE_profiles WHERE vendor_id = '$mvendorid'");

while($rst = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    print $rst[newcontainer] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  What happens?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: should $mvendorid be $vendorid

Comment: It will give a notice at `print` as the index `newcontainer` is not in quotes.

Comment: What is the output of mysql_error()? Add this line to match this: `while($rst = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) {`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got it working everyone thanks for all your answers. It was code above, pushing a vendor id into this sql statement which had no representative rows in the profiles table.

duh! well that happens when you dont have the luxury of peer review :-)

Comment: this should be a comment or update to the original post, not an answer in its own right. I suspect that's why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can i think...
but when you want to print it just add single quote like this 
`$rst['newcontainer']`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @toscho  it's an answer! maybe what  user1349089 is doing wrong is what salvo mentioned here!

Comment: @Death Missing quotes will raise a notice (and that should be fixed), but they do not stop execution.

Comment: Then PHP will generously convert the constant to a string. Test it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```
$query = "SELECT max(container_no) as newcontainer 
      FROM FETE_profiles WHERE vendor_id = ".$mvendorid." ";

    $result = $mysql->execute_sql_query($query);
    while(@$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
        print $rows['newcontainer ']. "<br/>";
    }
```